# Error after moving nodejs project to new mac

Tags: node.js, electron

I have a node project that I've m oved from one macbook to a new one. When I run npm start it throws and error (below). I've installed electron, node and gulp. I've tried re-installing all the packages. The error is a bit obscure and I'm stumped. Any thoughts really appreciated, thanks

```
% npm start                                                      

> tak_2@1.0.0 start
> electron .

node:internal/child_process:412
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn Unknown system error -86
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:412:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:698:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/kimaldis/Documents/Dev/Tak_2/node_modules/electron/cli.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  errno: -86,
  code: 'Unknown system error -86',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Node.js v17.3.1
```

Comment: try `npm cache verify` and `npm cache clean`

Comment: no joy, same error

Answer (score 0):

made a new directory, installed packages, copied the original files over and it all worked. Go figure.